# Calculating Beginning and Ending Balance SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, etl

I have difficulties in processing an ETL process using SQL Server. I must calculate beginning and ending balance, and the client only provide the Debit (will substract the balance) and Credit (will add the balance) transaction.

I have the table for illustration

[image: The bold part is where I have to do the calculation]

Any help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Did you want to calculate it while you are inserting into this table or do it as a post process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
SELECT 
    B.Date, 
    SUM(CR-DR) OVER(ORDER BY Date) - CR + DR AS Beginning,
    B.DR, B.CR, 
    SUM(CR-DR) OVER(ORDER BY Date) AS Ending 
FROM #bb AS B
```

Here is the sample data:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#bb') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #bb

CREATE TABLE #bb(
    Datum DATE,
    DR INT,
    CR INT
);

INSERT INTO #bb
(
    Datum,
    DR,
    CR
)
VALUES
(   '20180101', -- Datum - date
    100,         -- DR - int
    0          -- CR - int
),
(   '20180102', -- Datum - date
    0,         -- DR - int
    300          -- CR - int
),
(   '20180103', -- Datum - date
    150,         -- DR - int
    0          -- CR - int
);
```

And here is the result of that query:

```
Datum      Begining      DR          CR          Ending
---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
2018-01-01   0           100         0           -100
2018-01-02   -100        0           300         200
2018-01-03   200         150         0           50
```

Comment: If you want to get real cute, you can add `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING` after `ORDER BY Date` for your beginning expression, and avoid needing to manually adjust the value afterwards.

Comment: it works on the ending balance, but not beginning balance. The beginning balance should be carried by ending balance on the previous date

Comment: @MohammadIqbal - did you try it? In both cases, `SUM(CR-DR) OVER(ORDER BY Date)` sums the balance for all previous rows including the current row. Igor Ilic then *adjusts* `Beginning` by reversing the addition of `CR` and `DR` from the *current* row. My own comment above suggested another way to exclude the current row. The only way I can see this failing is if, in fact a) you're currently *storing* these balance totals and b) Your original starting balance isn't `0`. If either or both of these are the case, please update your question to make that clear.

Comment: It works! I just opening this pile of work again and tried your solution, Damien and Igor. It helps me a lot